Filling NoData values in raster with another raster's values in ArcGIS Pro using con(isnull())
I am currently working with two rasters in ArcGIS Pro: a masked raster (cloud_masked) where clouds and shadows have been removed, resulting in NoData values (holes), and an unmasked stacking raster (original_stack). Both rasters have the same size and resolution. I want to fill the NoData values in the cloud_masked raster with the corresponding values from the original_stack raster.
Here is what I have tried so far:
Using Raster Calculator with the Con Function
Con(IsNull("cloud_masked"), "original_stack", "cloud_masked")

When I used this method, the resulting raster turned out black instead of filling the NoData values correctly.
import arcpy from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/path_to_workspace"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
cloud_masked_path = "C:/path_to_workspace/cloud_masked.tif"
original_stack_path = "C:/path_to_workspace/original_stack.tif"
output_raster_path = "C:/path_to_workspace/filled_cloud_masked.tif"
cloud_masked_raster = Raster(cloud_masked_path)
original_stack_raster = Raster(original_stack_path)
filled_raster = Con(IsNull(cloud_masked_raster), original_stack_raster, cloud_masked_raster)
filled_raster.save(output_raster_path)
print(f"Filled raster saved to {output_raster_path}")

Things I have checked:

The NoData value settings for  cloud_masked
Ensuring both rasters have matching data types

How can I properly fill the NoData values without the resulting raster turning black?
Additionally, is there a better approach to handle the NoData values correctly?

Are you just missing statistics on the resulting raster?

Just me thinking out aloud, the fact you have deliberately named your input raster original_STACK.tif suggests to me that this a multi-band raster, i.e. a stack of bands. Not sure if CON() applies your logic to each band within the raster stack, you will need to check that. My experience with CON() is typically on a 1-band raster such as a DEM.

Yes, most Spatial Analyst functions operate on a single band only. If you pass a multiband raster, by default the first band is used. If "original_stack.tif has multiple bands, you need to apply the Con(IsNull()) functions to each band separately and then composite the output bands.
